# Where and how are the carrier and message signal multiplied in this circuit?

Tags: transistors, modulation, amplitude-modulation

I have this circuit diagram of an AM modulator and I am trying to understand what is going on.

I know that the *c(t)* is taken from the collector of transistor Q1 and the multiplication of signals : *m(t)c(t)* is taken from the collector of transistor Q2.

I want to know at what point and how the two signals *m(t)* and *c(t)* are multiplied.

[image]

Comment: Be careful of what you "know" about Q1,Q2 output. Both contain a version of *m(t)c(t)*.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks for letting me know, I knew I am wrong somewhere.  Can you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Ashwin, Andy's answer is good... **gain of the differential pair** (Q1, Q2) depends on current supplied by Q3. And Q3 is a fairly linear stage. Q1&Q2 collectors both contain many frequency components (50 Hz, 1kHz, 950Hz, 1050Hz, 2950Hz, 3000Hz, 3050Hz...and more). The diff-amp 741 stage eliminates 50Hz component, leaving the desired 950, 1000, 1050 components (plus the other higher-frequency components too :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find this [2-quadrant (Broadcast AM) multiplier explanation](http://www.iitk.ac.in/eclub/ee381/AnalogMultipliers.pdf) to be quite useful: -

[image]

What it's basically saying is that if you change \$I_{EE}\$ you can change the slope of the graph: -

[image]

I've drawn the red line on the graph above to indicate a lower value of \$I_{EE}\$. The linked document also goes on to show how \$I_{EE}\$ is "varied" using another transistor: -

[image]

> *I want to know at what point and how, are the two signals m(t) and
> c(t) multiplied.*

It's all done around Q1, Q2 and Q3 in your circuit. The differential amplifier that follows Q1 and Q2 converts the differential output of Q1 and Q2 to a single ended output.

Images above taken from [Analog Multipliers by School of Electronic and communications engineering](http://www.iitk.ac.in/eclub/ee381/AnalogMultipliers.pdf).

Another useful link from [Analog Devices MT-079 Analog Multipliers](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-079.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the explaination , I was very wrong about me knowing about the Q1 and Q2 part, i understand whats going on in the circuit now